# Prevent access to website depending on wheter or not it is viewed trough an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website(website a) that has only one Page, which i want to show on a different website(website b)  via iframe. But I want to prevent the access to website a.

Basicly what i want to do is this:

```
if (load website trough iframe == true){
         show website;
    }
else{
         don't open website;
     }
```

Anyone has a clue where to start to solve this problem?

Comment: There's this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Obligatory: [We Done Been ... Framed!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/we-done-been-framed/)

Answer (score 0):

Preventing access is a strong word. Here's how to check if you're in a frame or not.

```
if (window.frameElement) {
  // in frame
}
else {
  // not in frame... redirect to another page?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser will not provide access to `window.top` method. So you can use the following code to detect whether the website is running in an Iframe or Browser

```
function isInIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
if (isInIframe()){
    document.write("Show Website");
}
else{
    document.write("Don't Show Website");
}
```